# role of configuration classes in spring boot projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-ee-7

i am new to springboot application development and i generated my project with the help of this url https://start.spring.io/ and when i open this project in my IDE i had 2 classes generated
this is the first class

```
    public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer   {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder    configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TravellingApplication.class);
    }}
```

and this is the second class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TravellingApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TravellingApplication.class, args);
}}
```

i really don't get it whats happening inside the `configure method` in my `Servletinitializer` class.
i can write **better code configuration** if i delete both of the classes
and do something like this,

```
 class simmilar to dispatcherservlet.xml
 
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebMvc
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.travelliing")
 public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 }

  class simmilar to web.xml 

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws    ServletException { } 
}
```

correct me if i am wrong. i think both `ServletInitializer class` and `webAppInitializer` is capable of same functionalities since the somehow `implement WebApplicationInitializer`.
except for the `configure method in servletInitializer class`.

whats happening with the `travellingApplication class` annotated with **@SpringBootApplication** is it simmilar to my `webConfig Class` which extends `WebMvcConfigureAdapter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both classes load the Spring application context.

The class with the main method (`TravellingApplication`) will be used if you run your application as normal java application. For example if you do Run As -> Java applciatnion from Eclipse or if you package the application as a jar and run `java -jar myApp.jar` from the command line.

SpringBootServletInitializer will be used to load the application context if you package the application as a war file and deploy it in Tomcat or another web server that supports Servlet 3.0+. It basically replaces the `web.xml`.

> i really don't get it whats happening inside the configure method in
>   my Servletinitializer class.

TravellingApplication is a @Configuration class - it declares Spring beans and other Spring configuration, so this line - `return application.sources(TravellingApplication.class);` just loads this configuration (application context). The same thing that happens in the main method.

> whats happening with the travellingApplication class annotated with
>   @SpringBootApplication is it simmilar to my webConfig Class which
>   extends WebMvcConfigureAdapter

`@SpringBootApplication` is just a shortcut to

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @ComponentScan
```

See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html).

Comment: so u mean like `configure` method loads `application context` . exact same thing is happening in the `main method` which means i can remove `main method` from that class and use that class for `configuration` like i have done in my `WebConfig class`

Comment: @Priyamal Yes, but that way you have to deploy the app in an external web server and can't use the embedded web server like with the main method.